# window.location.reload refreshing the main window

Tags: html, dom, window, reload

the following is on a page, when i click it - I DO NOT want the page to refresh, but only the new window which this link opens - i want to refresh that newly opened page, not the main window.

clicking the link opens the new window correctly, but refreshes the main window also (where the link lies). that is undesirable and i want to know how to stop it from doing so.

```
<a href="" onclick="window.open('URL','mywin');mywin.location.reload();">clik to open new window</a>

<a href="" onclick="window.open('URL','mywin');">clik to open new window</a>
```

pl advice.

as advised below, but not working: infact it is breaking the new window, new window appears as blank window!

```
<a href="" onclick="mywin = window.open('URL','mywin');mywin.location.reload();">clik to open new window</a>
```

Comment: I don't get it, why would you want to reload a window right after opening it?

Comment: @bfavaretto You beat me to it, seems odd.

Comment: target window is opened twice, and then reloaded, due to some requirements. issue here is how to stop main window from refreshing. it refreshes even when i do not reload the target window.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the proper way to open a link in a new window. If javascript isn't available, the link will still work.

```
<a href="http://URL" onclick="window.open(this.href,'popupwindow');return false;">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: are you forgetting the target attribute?

Comment: the target attribute was removed from the XHTML spec, but web browsers still supported it, and it's back in HTML5. Old habits, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

`mywin` is a window name, not a variable.
You need to store the returned wobject from `window.open()` in a global variable:

```
onclick="window.mywin = window.open('URL','mywin');">
```

Comment: this is not working: i tried window.mywin and mywin also. task is to open new window with some args, then reopen the same window with new args. then reload that window. it is achieved using window_name, but i am not able to stop refresh of main window. even with mywin.location.reload().

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the main window reloading is likely the `href=""` line.  This could be causing the browser to navigate to the same page where it is presently (and therefore refreshing).  You should add `return false;` to the js, and likely also adopt a more standard link target like `href="#"` which will navigate to the top of the same page without a refresh (though this will still get cancelled by the `false` return).

Answer (score 0):

friends, it is resolved by doing this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('URL','mywin');">clik to open new window</a>
```